# What does "cite" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, verbs

This is a part of an article about "Paula Jones" from Wikipedia

"Paula Corbin Jones (born Paula Rosalee Corbin; September 17, 1966) is an American civil servant. A former Arkansas state employee, Jones sued United States President Bill Clinton for sexual harassment in 1994. In the initial lawsuit, **Jones cited Clinton** for sexual harassment at the Excelsior Hotel in Little Rock, Arkansas on May 8, 1991."

**"cite"**

to call upon officially or authoritatively to appear as before a court

This could be the sense here but I doubt it because  **It's the judge who summons someone before the court** and not the plaintiff. Am I right?

**"cite"**

2. To mention or bring forward as support, illustration, or proof: *cited several instances of insubordinate behavior*. (American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

This is the definition I lean toward. My doubt stems from the qualification "**as support, illustration, or proof**" in the definition. If Jones only mentioned that Clinton sexually harassed her, it makes sense to me because **she isn't providing any evidence** for it, **she is just saying** that he did it.

**"cite"**

4 British English to mention someone by name in a court case
Sue was cited in the divorce proceedings(Longman Dictionary)

This one is also probable but as the article is about American politics I suppose it **was written by an American**.

Comment: In US and UK English, not just judges, but parties in civil cases, and lawyers can 'cite' persons, see [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cite) 'LAW - specialised - to officially name or mention someone or something in a law court, or to officially request someone to appear in a court of law'. Example given: _He has been cited as the co-respondent in the divorce case._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In US and UK English, not just judges, but parties in civil cases (where people sue), and lawyers can 'cite' things or persons:

> cite verb
> [T] (NAME)
> LAW   specialized
>
> to officially name or mention someone or something in a law court, or to officially request someone to appear in a court of law:
>
> *The lawyer cited two similar cases.*
> *He has been cited as the co-respondent in the divorce case.*

[Cite (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cite)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I didn't know that. I'm not surprised because even the definition you provided doesn't specify **who** is requesting **" the presence of someone**, and the logical assumption is to suppose it's someone who has such a power(as a judge or magistrate).I guess it's pretty much the same in other dictionaries.

Comment: In your last comment in both cases you are talking about the sens of the word **"cite"** meaning **"mention"**, but I meant that only a judge has the capacity to **"cite"** meaning **"summon"** someone to appear in court. Also, I thought the second example about the co-respondent meant precisely that(to summon). The definition includes two senses of the word and I thought it would also contain two example sentences(one with each connotation)

Comment: @ Michael Harvey So just to clarify. Did you mean that "Jones cited Clinton for sexual harassment" means that she "mentioned him as someone who sexually assaulted her", in your answer?